# Netbeans (7.3) Adding HTML5 support in PHP

Tags: php, html, templates, netbeans

A normal HTML5 app in Netbeans will have support in Chrome browser. This normal HTML5 does not run on a Server, So both software there is only plain html code.

OK, i know this. But my question is,

I want the same support that html5 file editing/markup in chrome browser, for a php project (only html file, not php render file). If a php file has not support in browser (because of server). Can a plain html5 (without any php/twig code) file works like as a HTML5 project on Chrome.

If this is possible, can you please mention the way or settings to made in project or netbeans.

Comment: This was made possible in 7.4, so solution would be to try it on BETA builds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@dev-null-dweller thanks,

Download NetBeans 7.4 Beta 
http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/netbeans/7.4/beta/bundles/netbeans-7.4beta-php-linux.sh