# JavaScript Settings missing in PHP project settings

Tags: php, javascript, netbeans, netbeans-plugins

I'm using Netbeans 7.3.1.

I can see JavaScript Files section in my Netbeans projects settings when I create a HTML5 project.

But I want the same for my PHP projects. after all I want to be able to add dependencies as easily as I could, when using HTML5 project.

Is there a workaround to show JavaScript files in PHP projects?

Regards,

[image: HTML5 Prject Propertes]

[image: PHP Project Properties]

Comment: Answer is the same as here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17766635/258674

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I have NB7.4 Beta installed and a nightly build of NB as well but they turned out to be unstable for me.

Comment: In that case you have to wait until 7.4 gets stable release.